If B column number is bigger that the A column number return the first A column number in column c
I have a parent category key that I need to pair with the child number.



Parent
Child
Expected Output




1
1
1



2
1



3
1



4
1



5
1


6
6
6



7
6



8
6


9
9
9



10
9



I was using a combo of xlookups or index match, but it doesn't work because not every parent has the same number of children.
=IF(D14="",XLOOKUP(TRUE,D13:D75544>0,D13:D75544,,-1,1),"WRONG")
=INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(TRUE,A2:A7<>"",0))
I can't seem to get it to either ignore the blanks or not shift down incorrectly.

This sort of table, I would fill col A blanks with the cell above it. Highlight the range, then select blanks only via "Find & Select" and then put =[cell above cur cell] and CTRL + Enter to fill them. Then in column C put =If(B2>=A2, A2) I don't know what you want you false condition to be, and based on your data you want >= not simply >

Assuming Parent is column A and EXP.Output is column C, put the formula
=IF(A2<>"",A2,C1)

in C2 & copy it to the rest of that column.
(The idea is that if the Parent is missing in a row, repeat the Output from the previous row.)

unfortunately it only works if there is data in column A, otherwise the result is 0.

So there might not be data in A2?  In that case, what should go in C2?  When I use this on the table you provided, it produced the column you asked for.

I would bet that A2 is not blank or "" but either masked to show blank or there is some unprinted character in the cell.

A solution not dependent on the value of the parent, using FILTER for to get the last non-empty parent. May not be that performant, could be useful still.

Define the data range containing the parent data, here named as parent.

Create a named function parent_above in Name Manager:
=MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(parent)), 
LAMBDA(_i,  LET(_above, TAKE(parent,_i),  TAKE(FILTER(_above,_above<>""),-1))))


Enter the following anywhere with at least the same number of empty rows as in parent.
=IF(TRIM(parent)<>"",parent, parent_above)





Limit rows to filter
To improve performance, add a named value, here as row_limit and update the formula to
=MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(parent)), 
LAMBDA(_i,  
LET(
_all_above, TAKE(parent,_i), 
_above, IF(ROWS(_all_above) > row_limit, TAKE(_all_above, -row_limit), _all_above),   TAKE(FILTER(_above,_above<>""),-1))))


Good old LOOKUP does exactly that:
=LOOKUP(B2:B11,A2:A11)

